# SQL ORACLE UPDATE with Join

Tags: sql, oracle

How to set an update statement in Oracle SQL with a join.  Example not working.
I would like to edit table F1 by selecting the records from F2 with the join.

```
UPDATE F1
SET    a1b2 = 58585, a1b3 = 98989 
FROM   FILE1 F1 
JOIN   FILE2 F2 ON F1.KEY = F2.KEY 
WHERE  F2.IDNBR = 99999
```

Comment: From the SO Documentation area: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/8061/update-with-joins#t=201701190021526575307

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?" And what do you mean "how to set up an update statement?" What are you trying to do? What did you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers." You include neither the desired behavior nor a specific problem or error.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement right, then it is about updating values `a1b2` and `a1b3` in file1 for all those rows which have a corresponding row in `file2` with an `IDNBR=9999`. Then, I'd not use a join but a simple `exists`-check as follows:

```
UPDATE file1 SET a1b2 = 58585, a1b3 = 98989
where exists (
  select * from FILE2 F2 where file1.KEY = F2.KEY and F2.IDNBR = 99999)
```

Yes, this works!  A little rusty with clauses.  Thank you.

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: @RBT: Done; Hope it's better now.

Comment: I would like to edit table F1 by selecting the records from F2 with the join.

Comment: You're welcome. Please do not forget to accept the answer, such that the topic can be closed. Thanks!

Comment: I believe the answer is closed, correct?

Comment: No, it is not accepted yet. There should be a green check to click on...